# Access tkinter entry from external function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scope

I need to access the contents of an Entry widget from outside the function in which they are defined. 
I have a main window, which calls a function to create another window:

```
def submit():
    print(entry.get())

def function():
    window2 = Tk()
    …
    entry = Entry(window2)
    button2 = Button(window2, command=submit)
    …
    window2.mainloop()

window = Tk()
…
button = Button(window, command=function)
...
window.mainloop()
```

However the entry widget is out of scope, so cannot be seen by the function. Is there a way to do this without using global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do for tkinter. Like with any object in python, you need to keep a reference to an object if you want to access the object.

For example, you sould make `entry` a global variable. Or, you could have `function` pass then `entry` widget to the `submit` function as a parameter.

Here's an example of the latter:

```
def submit(entry):
    print(entry.get())

def function():
    ...
    entry = Entry(window2)
    button2 = Button(window2, command=lambda entry=entry: submit(entry))
```

---

You're going to have other problems -- you should never create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`. Also, you should almost never call `mainloop` more than once. You only need a single instance running.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `StringVar()` which is a class from tkinter. It's used so that you can easily monitor changes to tkinter variables .

```
part_text = StringVar() # Create a string var which acts like a text holder
part_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=part_text) # pass it to the entry
part_text.get() #this is how to access the text in the entry anywhere in your script
```

Comment: `StringVar` doesn't solve this problem, it just moves it a bit. They will have the same problem accessing the instance of `StringVar` as they now have with accessing the entry widget.